# format TextView text Android

Tags: android, textview

I've got a String Array in my main.xml and by pressing a Button it displays a random string in the textview. But Ive got a Problem. So basically its a quotes app and the Quote should be in quotationmarks. And the second quotationmark should be with the last word not in a own line. How can I modify the Strings that the last Word is always with the second quotationmark?

Here a picture: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be newline character before second quotation mark. You can give a try by removing second quotation mark using subString() method and then manually adding second quotation mark.

Comment: no its just for some strings... the most strings are sisplayed normal. But some arent, like in the picture. Is there a way to set it in xml that i will be alway displayed sideby side, like it is one word?

Comment: I am not sure about xml but you can easily edit it before displaying it in textview.

Comment: hmm idont know which string i have to formate, because it depends on the widht f the textview, when the quotationmark is displayed in a new line... :-S

Comment: You can check like this, if your string last character is quotation mark, " this is a sample quote. ", you can replace the quotation mark and space by quotation mark, in that way it will stick to last word and won't jump to new line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you escaping the quotation mark correctly?

[Formating and Styling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

So if you want a String with quotations marks you need something like this.

```
textView.setText("\"hello world\"");
```